# Ignoring content below certain ID in Wikipedia using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

In the following links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America

I need to grab the content inside the h2, h3 and p tags. HOWEVER, I want to ignore the header and the content in:

1. "See Also"
2. "Notes"
3. "References"
4. Ignore all tables/urls

How would I accomplish this in Beautiful Soup? My current code is as follows:

```
    def open_document():
    for i in range (1, 1+1):
        with open(directory_of_raw_documents + str(i), "r") as document:
            html = document.read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
            body = soup.find('div', id='bodyContent')
            results = ""
            for item in body.find_all(['h2','h3','p']):
                results += item.get_text() + "\n"
                results = results.replace("[edit]","")
            print(results)

open_document()
```

My desired output would not have any content in any table, See All, Notes, or Reference sections. I would prefer to not use the Wikipedia module in Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
soup.find(something)
```

means you are find something in whole document,
if you want to ignore some contents, you need to narrow the scope,in you case, you can use:

```
soup.find(id = 'bodyContent') #this narrow the scope to the main content.
```

than you can use find_all:

```
soup.find(id = 'bodyContent').find_all(name=['h2','h3','p'], href=False)
```